# How to switch from using github files to using local (modified but not committed) files in an R project?

Tags: r, git

I have an R project that I am debugging in RStudio.

I initially included the R project using this:

```
devtools::install_github("OHDSI/ETL-Synthea@bae1c8eca8dba7ba1129f6c5f758b985c5458405")
library(ETLSyntheaBuilder)
```

I can debug the existing code using something like this:

```
fun <- function() {
  ETLSyntheaBuilder::LoadEventTables(connectionDetails = cd, cdmSchema = cdmSchema, syntheaSchema = syntheaSchema, cdmVersion = cdmVersion, syntheaVersion = syntheaVersion)
}

debug(fun)

fun()
```

When I debug the code like this I can step through what looks like the code base from the original github checkout.

What do I need to do to be able to make modification to the code locally and step through (debug) my local version?

Ideally, I would like to be able to step through my local version without having to commit every time I make a change I would like to test.

I would like to minimize the changes I need to make to the actual R files so I don't need to change them back when I commit the changes back to the source.

Comment: If you are just debugging it to work through something, then `git clone https://github.com/OHDSI/ETL-Synthea.git` (to a local dir) and then [`git checkout` that commit reference](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/git-checkout-commits). If you are intending to submit a pull-request on changes, I'll assume you do not have permissions on the origin repo, in which case you'll need to fork it first to your own github account (assuming you have that) and then `git clone ssh://...` _that_ repo locally first (at which point you'd need to decide on which commit to base your changes).

Comment: (Once you clone it to a local directory, you'd instead use `devtools::load_all("path/to/ETL-Synthea/")`.)